# Confused with removeAllViewsInLayout(), postInvalidate() and refreshDrawableState()

Tags: android

I am really confused with this three functions: `removeAllViewsInLayout()`, `postInvalidate()` and `refreshDrawableState()`.

```
removeAllViewsInLayout()
```

When I use `removeAllViewsInLayout()` in my program, all views were gone. But when trigger `postInvalidate()` to refresh, nothing. I think `removeAllViewsInLayout()` deletes all of my views. Is there a way to clear all things in my view but not delete it?

```
postInvalidate()
```

I want to refresh my view. But with `refreshDrawableState()`, I can do only once, why?

Comment: What kind of views are you working with? What exactly do you want to accomplish?

Comment: i create view in java just "extends View" and use canvas draw some shapes on it. I want to find a way to delete all shapes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you call `postInvalidate()` (or just call `invalidate()` if on the UI thread), the system will schedule a redraw of your view. Your `onDraw()` method can then do whatever it wants, including just drawing a blank canvas.

If you call `removeAllViewsInLayout()` it will do just that -- remove every view, including your custom view. You probably don't want to do that. (EDIT: `removeAllViewsInLayout()` is intended to be called only as part of layout calculations for a `ViewGroup`. A typical use would be by a `ViewGroup` that "owns" a large number of views but during `onLayout()` processing decides to display only those children that actually fits on the screen. If you are not in the process of computing the view layout, you should call `removeAllViews()` instead.)

Calling `refreshDrawableState()` is only useful if your view is using a `Drawable` object that is sensitive to the state of the view. For example, a Button will use this so that the background drawable changes color when the button is pressed. For what you are doing, you don't need to bother with this method, either.

Comment: additionally, if I want to just clean the view (make all stuff I created disappear) how can I do that?

Comment: @nich - The stuff you created -- is that a display list that is rendered in onDraw? If so, just clear the display list and invalidate the view. When onDraw executes again, just don't draw anything.